# Session porting

Tags: java, php, session, porting

How to carry a session which is made with some language i.e (java) on some website(www.example1.com) to the website made with other language i.e (php) on some other website i.e (www.example2.com).

Comment: I think this is a perfectly good question; Storing sessions in Databases is an excellent item to learn about.  +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store your sessions in a database or other language-agnostic storage layer (I use Redis for sessions, personally). Then just make sure both applications can read/write to the session store using the same session format.

Answer (score 0):

carry session means you probably want to carry session variables to another website or webapp. This seems weird but what you can probably do is write a method to accept the sesion variables from a particular server host and accept it.

Comment: actually i have an existing eCommerce site which is in asp.net 2.0 .I want to carry session variable which is generated when we add products to cart.I want this session variable to get linked to drupal site which is hosted probably on sub-domain.Do you think it is possible?

Comment: As of what i know it is not impossible. You might have to send the session credentials via the web to the other app.